# Creating a CiviEvent, all options except 'Info and Settings' are disabled

Tags: civievent

How do I enable those options so I can complete the event configuration, including a registration form?  Exploring the Administer -> CiviEvent options provides me with no clues.  (CiviCRM 5.28.alpha1)

Comment: can you compare what you are observing with what happens at eg https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

Comment: In my installation, at: /civicrm/event/manage/registration?reset=1&action=update&id=162&component=event, I am unable to configure a registration form.  The option is greyed out.  On the demo site, this path /civicrm/event/manage/registration?reset=1&action=update&id=3#/volunteer/manage/0 gives me a form to configure an event registration form.

Comment: I investigated the user permissions available in the cms (drupal).  For the admin user, all CiviEvent permissions are enabled.

Comment: have you; filled in Info and Settings and saved, does it create the event, and then when you go back to add more info are the tabs not responding?

Comment: Exactly.  It saves the 'info and settings', just does not allow me to configure or view a registration form or perform any of the other available tasks, listing them as greyed-out.